# What does the eth0 interface name mean in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking

What do the Linux interface names mean?

- eth0
- eth1
- wlan0

My current assumption is that when we are connected to the Internet via LAN cable it's eth0 or eth1 and when we are connected with internet via WiFi it's wlan0.

Comment: Do note that some distros (Fedora and probably others) name devices differently: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/System_Administrators_Guide/appe-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming.html. The goal was to avoid ambiguity (e.g. multiple network cards in a system).

Comment: the good ol' time when an ethernet interface was called eth0 and not enp0s25!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.

The names however can be set/chosen by the user or the operating system that you are using. `eth0` and `eth1` is used because it's more intuitive than choosing an arbitrary name because "LAN cable" connection, like you said is Ethernet (hence the `eth` in `eth0, eth1`). Similarly when you connect to WiFi, it's "WirelessLAN" (hence the `wlan` in `wlan0`).

Answer (score 8):

*eth0* is the first ethernet interface, any additional ethernet interfaces would be named *eth1*, *eth2*, etc.